# Merging Arrows to Show Implications in Tikz-CD

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'm trying to create a diagram with logical implications between various propositions, and some of them are conjunctions. Suppose I want to show this:

```
 A => C
 A&B => D
```

the best I can get so far is this, but there's still some space that I can't get rid of:

```
$$\begin{tikzcd}
     a\arrow[d,Rightarrow]
      \arrow[dr,Rightarrow,""{name=A}] 
   & b\arrow[to=A,Rightarrow,dash] \\
   c & d
\end{tikzcd}$$
```

[image: rendered diagram]

I feel this must be a common problem and probably I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In general you should post a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Also, it's usually [best to use `\[..\]` instead of `$$..$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, since the placement and length of the `equals` arrow was found by trial and error. For a different diagram you'd have to make adjustments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
     a\arrow[d,Rightarrow]
      \arrow[dr,Rightarrow,""{name=A, xshift=4.85pt}] 
   & b\arrow[to=A, equals, shorten >=-8.75pt] \\
   c & d
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The `shorten >` key can be used with a negative value to increase the length of the `equals` arrow. Note the required space between `shorten` and `>`.

Comment: I had not understood the request of the user. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, I didn't understand either until I saw the comment on your post. I was going to suggest the same thing you did.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, that's what I wanted to get. Thanks also for the reference on using \\[ \\] over $$.